# Kafka producer fails fetching metadata from broker

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, spark-streaming, kafka-producer-api

I'm hosting Kafka on three separate nodes, each with local Zookeeper instances. When producing to the topic `live`, I get the below exception. `metadata.brokers.list` is not set to `localhost`, but `kafka1.domain.com`, `kafka2.domain.com`, `kafka3.domain.com`. The `advertised.host.name` is set to the local IP address of the Amazon instances. There are no references to `localhost` in the Kafka setup.

This is the producer config:

```
props.put("metadata.broker.list", "kafka1.domain.com:9092,kafka2.domain.com:9092,kafka3.domain.com:9092")
props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")
props.put("producer.type", "async")
props.put("batch.num.messages", "1000")
props.put("queue.buffering.max.ms", "20000")
props.put("request.required.acks", "0")
```

Every `producer.send` produces the exceptions.

Anyone know what might be wrong?

```
WARN ClientUtils$: Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 5 for topics [Set(live)] from broker [id:0,host:localhost,port:9092] failed
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
        at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
        at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.getBrokerPartitionInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:49)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.kafka$producer$async$DefaultEventHandler$$getPartitionListForTopic(DefaultEventHandler.scala:186)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$partitionAndCollate$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:150)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$partitionAndCollate$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.partitionAndCollate(DefaultEventHandler.scala:149)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.dispatchSerializedData(DefaultEventHandler.scala:95)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:72)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:105)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:94)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:45)
ERROR DefaultEventHandler: Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(live)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:localhost,port:9092)] failed
WARN ClientUtils$: Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 6 for topics [Set(live)] from broker [id:0,host:localhost,port:9092] failed
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
        at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$2.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
        at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172)
        at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
        at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:105)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:94)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:45)
ERROR Utils$: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(live)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:localhost,port:9092)] failed
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(live)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:localhost,port:9092)] failed
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
        at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$2.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
        at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172)
        at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
        at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:105)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:94)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:45)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
        ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the `kafka.producer.Producer` in `kafka:0.8.2.1`. Apparently it is bugged, and by going for the `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer` in `kafka-clients:0.8.2.1` instead, it worked instantly without any problems on the same config.